# The resource cannot be found. MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do ajax call to my controller that uses HttpPost method

**AJAX CALL**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#contactDiv ').click(function() {

           var  number = $(this).find('.ContactNumber').text();

            var dataJson = {"contactNumber": number};
           // var dataJson = {"contactNumber": number };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../contactWeb/messages",
               data: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
               //data: dataJson,
                 contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    //msg for success and error.....
                    // alert(msg);

                    return true;
                }
            });
            location.href = '@Url.Action("messages")';
        });

    });
```

**CONTROLLER**

[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult messages(string contactNumber) 
    {
        // return the app messages of a pirticular user on contact basis
        Int64 userID = Convert.ToInt64(Session["userId"]);
        try
        {
            List messagesModel = new List();
            IMessages MessageObject = new MessagesBLO();

```
        messagesModel = MessageObject.GetAllMessagesWeb(userID , contactNumber);

        ViewData["Data"] = messagesModel;



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    return View();

   // string msg = "Error while Uploading....";
    //return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult messages()
{


    return View();

    // string msg = "Error while Uploading....";
    //return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**VIEW "messages" is**

```
@model OyeAPI.Models.PhoneMessages
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "messages";
    List<Model.MessagesModel> ListMessages = (List<Model.MessagesModel>)ViewData["Data"];

    Int64 MessageId = 0;
    Int64  SenderId = 0;
    Int64 ReceiverId = 0;
    string  Message = null;
    string  Date = null;
    string SendReceive = null;
    int  MessageType = 0;


}
<div class="main_Container">
    <div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Message ID</td><td>SenderID</td><td>recieverID</td><td>message</td><td>date</td>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in ListMessages) 
            {
                MessageId = item.MessageId;
                SenderId = item.SenderId;
                ReceiverId = item.ReceiverId;
                Message = item.Message;
                Date = item.Date.ToShortDateString();
                SendReceive = item.SendReceive;
                MessageType = item.MessageType;

                     <tr>
                        <td>@MessageId</td>
                        <td>@SenderId</td>
                        <td>@ReceiverId</td>
                        <td>@Message</td>
                        <td>@Date</td>
                    </tr>



            }

        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

it returns Resource not found error which is very annoying to me because i tried to delete and rebuilt the view but still unable to solve it.and one thing else what i want to do in this code is that with ajax call i send the contactNo to controller on the basis of which it checks the corresponding messages of this contactno number and pass it to its view messages. so when the ajax call response is successfully done then it will redirect to messages view.

Comment: Instead of `"../contactWeb/messages"` use `"@Url.Action("messages","contactWeb")"` if your JS is in CSHTML file

Comment: You can't return a View to an ajax call, you need to send back a result in json, And i am using "/ControllerName/Action" and it's just fine.

Comment: "Resource not found" when exactly this error occurs? While calling ajax request or in controller?

Comment: @AshwiniVerma /contactWeb/messages error is the resource either may have been deleted or its name changed..something like this after the ajax request response is succesful

Comment: Try using what @Satpal said. Thats way you dont have to worry about the URLs.

Comment: Use asp.net web api for this and return a JSON result for that

Comment: then change url how Satpal suggested. "@Url.Action("messages","contactWeb")"

Comment: What is that last statement trying to do? `location.href = '@Url.Action("messages")';` ? this will not work. Remove it and everything should be fine.

Comment: @Satpal tried what you said its not working ....

Answer (score 3):

I think this line in your javascript that makes you get a 404 - not found error :

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("messages")';
```

I assume that it tries to redirect to the very same controller which code you write in the question, which is marked with `[HttpPost]`.

So what happen is, you try to `GET` a resource that is marked as `[HttpPost]`.

The solution is to remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute, or provide another `messages` action in that controller that accept a `GET` request.

Comment: looks that your answers is alot help for me. now its giving me error in my view "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on for each loop

Comment: I think this not causing to access the controller since you are making ajax post request and controller is also [HttpPost].

Comment: @AshwiniVerma : the ajax `post` request is successful, what causing the error is the redirection, which is always a `get` request

Comment: @user3359326 : I don't see any loop on your code. And because you're catching all `Exception`, then chances are what causing that error is the `Convert` part of your code...

Comment: @andri   is right the problem is with get request AshwinVerma

Comment: I have added my View also now you can see what i meant that

Comment: @andri what i think is that the error is because of the return view() in both get and post method, but i have checked it when i return null in get method it gives me no error but also no data on my view also.... every thing is wiped out nothing is showing when i use return null in get()

Comment: @user3359326 : have you tried using the same action for both `GET` and `POST`?

Comment: yes...i have tried it...i changed the code as for [HttpGet]public void messages and for [httpPost] is  use the same as mentioned in my question it works fine with no error but still showing no data to me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no any custom authorize attribute set for Controller.

If it is, mark this particular controller with [AllowAnonymous] attribute.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult messages(string contactNumber)
    {
    }
```

Comment: if it's an authorization problem, the response should be `401 - Unauthorized`, not `404`

Comment: this is the error below.
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source Error: 
Line 25:       
Line 26: 
Line 27:             @foreach (var item in ListMessages) 
Line 28:             {
Line 29: